# bundle install problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gemfile

ok whenever I run "bundle install" I get this

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    sass-rails (~> 3.1.0.rc8) depends on
      railties (~> 3.1.0)

    railties (3.1.0.rc8)
```

now in my gem file i have this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0.rc8"
#added by me
  gem 'railties', " ~> 3.1.0.rc8"
#end
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

I am using ubuntu and I am new to ruby, I am trying to run a simple application.

Any help ? thx!

Comment: Can you try gem 'rails', '3.1.0' instead '3.1.0.rc8' ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Rails 3.1 has been released today, you have to update your Gemfile as:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug'
```

You do not need the `railties` line neither since this gem is included in rails.
Then, run `bundle install`. That should do the trick.