# git push heroku master

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bundler

I ran into a problem in the heroku part, and got stuck here. The following were the command I input and the result it came out.I installed ruby on rails with the railsinstaller.

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\first_app>git push heroku master
Counting objects: 64, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (51/51), done.
Writing objects: 100% (64/64), 26.12 KiB, done.
Total 64 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.2.0.pre
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs bin/
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
       In Gemfile:
       rails (= 3.2.1) ruby depends on
       railties (= 3.2.1) ruby
       jquery-rails (= 2.0.0) ruby depends on
       railties (3.2.5)

 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:empty-fire-5502.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:empty-fire-5502.git'
```

Comment: Can you append your Gemfile? It appears that you have a conflict between rails versions. You have something requiring rails 2.3.1 and then railties 3.2.5. This error is saying that you have to pick one essentially.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dependency conflict for a '**railties**' gem. It's trying to load different versions of a same gem.

If you have specified '**railties**' gem in you Gemfile, try removing it. Its already included when you specify the '**rails**' gem.

And also, this SO question looks similar to your problem [bundle install problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256812/bundle-install-problem)